# How to populate an ArrayList from words in a text file?

Tags: java, arraylist, file-handling

I have a text file containing words separated by newline , like the following format:

```
>hello  
>world  
>example
```

How do i create an ArrayList and store each word as an element?

Comment: It looks like a common homework assignment - please add the tag, if it the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use apache commons [`FileUtils.readLines()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29).

I *think* the `List` it returns is already an `ArrayList`, but you can use the constructor [`ArrayList(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) to make sure you get one.

Answer (score 3):

The *simplest* way is to use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

```
File file = new File("foo.txt");
List<String> words = Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

(It's not guaranteed to be an `ArrayList`, but I'd *hope* that wouldn't matter.)

Answer (score 3):

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    File file = new File("names.txt");
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    while (in.hasNextLine()){
        names.add(in.nextLine());
    }
    Collections.sort(names);
    for(int i=0; i<names.size(); ++i){
        System.out.println(names.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You read the file line-by-line, create an ArrayList for Strings, and add line.substring(1) to the defined ArrayList if line.length>0.

Comment: I used line.substring(1) because his sample contains that he has a '>' at beginning of each line.

Answer (score 0):

I put the file at "C:\file.txt"; if you run the following it fils an ArrayList with the words and prints them.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:\\file.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
            lines.add(line.replace(">", ""));
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        for(String l : lines) {
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: As mentioned on Adam's answer, I'd recommend using an InputStreamReader and specifying an encoding. Also, you should have a try/finally block so that you can close the file regardless. (Not a problem in a tiny sample, but I wouldn't want the OP to lift this code directly into a utility method.)

Comment: yes ok, it could use some polishing, but it does what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure they're lots of libraries that do this with 1 line, but here's a "pure" Java implementation:

Notice that we've "wrapped"/"decorated" etc. a standard FileReader (which only has read one byte at a time) with a BufferedReader which gives us a nicer readLine() method.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream("test.txt"),
            Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
    System.out.println(lines);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will use the default character encoding, which isn't usually a good idea. I'd suggest using InputStreamReader wrapped around a FileInputStream. Also, the `close` call should be in a `finally` block. I'd suggest letting the `IOException` bubble up to the caller, too.